# How to add and remove elements dynamically JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this let's say quiz maker where I create questions. It looks like this:

[image]

The user can choose to display this rating system in 4 different ways:

1. **1 2 3 4 5** -> 1-5 rating
2. **1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10** -> 1-10 rating
3. **⭐ ⭐ ⭐ ⭐ ⭐** -> 1-5 stars
4. **⭐ ⭐ ⭐ ⭐ ⭐ ⭐ ⭐ ⭐ ⭐ ⭐** -> 1-10 stars

The default rating system is from 1 to 5 numbers. But the user has the option to make it from 1 to 10 using the toggle switch as well as stars instead of numbers. My problem is that I don't know how to add 5 more numbers when the switch is turned on and then when it turned off remove them again, or remove the numbers and add stars when the other toggle switch is turned on.

I imagine that I need something like:

```
depending on the current state:
if (1-10_switch.isChanged){
   (addMore(stars || numbers) || remove ) 
}
else if (stars_switch.isChanged){
   (changeIconTo(stars || numbers)) 
}
```

I have the code to check if the switch goes on and off:

```
oneToTenButtonCheckbox.addEventListener("change", function () {
    OneToTen = OneToTen ? false : true;
});

starsButtonCheckbox.addEventListener("change", function () {
    isStars = isStars ? false : true;
});
```

And this is the code where I add the numbers:

```js
  var numbersDiv = document.createElement("div");  
  numbersDiv.className = "row";
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var num = document.createElement("div");
    num.insertAdjacentText("beforeend", i + 1);
    if (i == 0) num.className = "col-1 offset-1 mb-2";
    else num.className = "col-1 mb-2";
    numbersDiv.appendChild(num);
  }
```

Does anyone know what approach I can use to solve this? Or maybe someone has done it and know how to do? Thanks.

Comment: Can we see HTML part, of the numbersDiv?

Comment: Why do these numbers need to get displayed at this point to begin with? The user that is creating the question here in this place, is not the one who will actually be rating it - no? If this is pure _display_ at this point, and there is no more functionality attached to these numbers - then I would simply toggle a class on the parent element, that shows the second half ...

Comment: @aca i added it but i don't think it matters that much

Comment: @CBroe You are right, the user who is creating is not the one who would be rating. There is no functionality at this point. Only visual

Comment: you can create all the rating blocks upfront, attach an additional class for elements 6-10. Then toggle hide/show for those objects based on selection

Comment: I see what you guys are saying. Although the next step is the user to choose between stars and numbers. So if I am then showing and hiding it won't work because the place for the numbersDiv will be occupied already and the starsDiv will have to be placed underneath the hidden numbersDiv if I follow this approach.

What I want to do is for example remove the numbers and in the place of those numbers, add stars

Comment: it will work. you can just swap one div (let's say the number div) with another (the stars div) by effectively changing the visibility of both (they overlap each other). if you want to go ahead with your approach, [here](https://jsbin.com/mumobusume/2)'s a crude example

Comment: I'm not sure I correctly got it.. but according to my understanding you have 2 toggle switches ruling the same thing. So when you toggle the value for `1-10` it should automatically trigger the toggling of `Stars`. The UI this way is very confusing while instead it could be the same UI-control having two options. The logic to show/hide the 1-10/1-5 is as easy as having two html blocks that you just toggle visible/hidden. Creating and removing is just a waste of time and complexity. And it got 4 upvotes.. sometimes it's a mistery to me

Comment: @DiegoDeVita No, I have 2 toggle switches, one for 1-10 and one for stars. so there are 4 possibilities (1-5 numbers, 1-10 numbers, 1-5 stars, 1-10 numbers).

Comment: I will edit my question so it includes the stars as well

Comment: It was an element not strictly bound to the question that confused me... but indeed you didn't mention it expicitely in your logic so it was fair enough. My bad. Anyway I know you may prefer to go with the strategy you already decided.. but seriously.. you might just have a sequence of elements for 1 to 10 and embed the segment 6-10 inside a container that will be toggled a css class having display:none. Wouldn't it be enough? no because you are asking how to create and remove.. ok. :) fiy I will add here the template option https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

Comment: @DiegoDeVita I can understand your approach and it will work if I only had numbers. Although I am not sure if it would work for the stars as well

Comment: my approach would work even if those div contained videos. It's just html.. anyway never mind. The answers in queue will surely adopt nice solutions by creating and removing elements. Frankly I know the bigger picture there, it's much bigger than it seems and it surely deserved a better approach. But it's hard to tell by looking at it so close.

Comment: Okay well you should know better than me. I will try what was suggested my you as well as the answers and I will try to solve this.

Comment: It is not clear how you display stars or numbers. The CSS classes are not provided. I don't see anything in your code that determines what is displayed or where a number is output.

Comment: @trincot Yeah, I am not using any CSS. For the moment I am just using the character ⭐ for the stars and normal numbers for the numbers.

Comment: So where in your code do you output those characters? It seems not included in your question.

Comment: Well this code is a part of a bigger one that is for the whole question. Let's say whatever i put in the `numbersDiv` is being shown at that place where the numbers are. I can do another div if it's needed

Comment: The more concrete you make it the better the answers will align with it. The more you leave open and undetermined, the less likely the answers will match what you really need. Anyway, I have posted an answer that takes the CSS route.

Comment: After checking all the answers I solved it using the `div.replaceChild()` function. It's nice to discover new and different ways to approach a problem so thank you to all who spent time on this

Answer (score 3):

I would not generate that HTML dynamically. Create it upfront, and hide the last 5 elements with a CSS class. The numbers can be generated with a CSS counter at the start as well.

With this set up the code only needs to toggle CSS classes:

```js
const answer = document.querySelector("#answer");
document.querySelector("#oneToTenButtonCheckbox").addEventListener("change", () => {
    answer.children[1].classList.toggle("hidden");
});
document.querySelector("#starsButtonCheckbox").addEventListener("change", () => {
    answer.classList.toggle("stars");
});
```

```css
body {
    counter-reset: star-num;
}
#answer.stars > span > span::after {
    content: "⭐";
}
#answer > span > span::after {
    counter-increment: star-num;
    content: counter(star-num);
}
#answer > span > span {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30px;
}
.hidden {
    display: none
}
```

```html
<label><input type=checkbox id="oneToTenButtonCheckbox">1 - 10</label><br>
<label><input type=checkbox id="starsButtonCheckbox">Stars</label><br>
 
<div id="answer">
    <span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span></span><span class="hidden"><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take the logic of creating the numbers and enter it into a function:

```
var numbersDiv = document.createElement("div");  
numbersDiv.className = "row";

function createNumbers(startNumber, endNumber)
  for (let i = startingNumber; i <= endNumber; i++) {
    var num = document.createElement("div");
    // add id so you can delete later
    num.id = "ratingNumber" + i;
    num.insertAdjacentText("beforeend", i);
    if (i == 1) num.className = "col-1 offset-1 mb-2";
    else num.className = "col-1 mb-2";
    numbersDiv.appendChild(num);
  }
}

//initial call to create 1-5
createNumbers(1, 5)
```

Then, he event handler receives the event itself as an argument, and in a case of a change event for HTML checkbox (I assume this is a checkbox due to the variable name), the event consists a `checked` property, so you can change the event listener:

```
oneToTenButtonCheckbox.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
    event.checked ? createNumbers(6, 10) : removeNumbers(6, 10); 
});
```

Then create a `removeNumbers` method:

```
function removeNumbers(startNumber, endNumber) {
    for (let i = startNumber; i <= endNumber; i++) {
        const numToRemove = document.getElementById("ratingNumber" + i);
        numToRemove.remove()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add new elements:

```
// first: make a new element
let li = document.createElement('li')
// second:add new element to Parent Node(such as ul)
//Insert at the end of the parent element
ul.appendChild(li)
//Insert into the specified position of the parent element
ul.insertBefore(li, ul.children[0])
//Please note that before you add the DOM child nodes (step 2) please complete the processing you need to do for the child nodes
```

remove elements:

```
ul.removeChild(li)
```

try use this in your code ,Hope its could help you

Answer (score 1):

A simple/straightforward way is to :

1. Store the status of `isTen` and `isStar`, which are both default to `false`
2. Create a `toggle()` function to change these status when the switch is clicked.
3. Generate the content according to these two flag (i.e. `display()`).

```js
isTen = false;
isStar = false;
display()

function toggle(flag){
  /* toggle the corresponding flag */
  if (flag == "isTen"){
    isTen = !isTen;
  }else{
    isStar = !isStar;
  }
  /* generate display with latest flag */
  display()
}

function display(){
  /* generate the output string with isTen and isStar flag*/
  n = isTen ? 10 : 5;
  output = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      if (isStar){
         output += "⭐";
      } else {
         output += i+1;
      }
  }
  /* clear the display span first*/
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "";
  /* show output string on display span */
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = output;
  showStatus();
}

function showStatus(){
  document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "isTen : "+isTen+"<br>isStar :"+isStar;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle('isTen')">
  isTen
</label>
<br>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle('isStar')">
  isStar
</label>
<br>
<span id="display"></span>
<br><br><br>
<span id="status"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my completely dynamic and general solution. I came up with a dynamic solution because I'm assuming that you'll need to create multiple quizzes thus multiple rating selectors.

We can create a rating selector element with the `createRatingSelector` function and it returns a **HTMLDivElement**.

```js
const stateElement = document.getElementById("state");

const quizRatingSelector = createRatingSelector({
  altRatingScale: 10,
  defaultRatingScale: 5,
  altRatingType: "star",
  defaultRatingType: "number",
  altRatingTypeLabel: "Star",
  defaultRatingTypeLabel: "Number Scale",

  // listen to change event
  onChange: ({ratingScale, ratingType}) => {
    const stateString = `scale: ${ratingScale}, type: ${ratingType}`;
    stateElement.innerText = stateString;
  },
});

document.body.appendChild(quizRatingSelector);

// we can get the current state as
// console.log(quizRatingSelector.getState());

// ------------------------------------------

// returns a <div> element
// see the argument destructuring below to understand function API
function createRatingSelector(arg = {}) {
  const {
    altRatingType,
    altRatingScale,
    defaultRatingType,
    altRatingTypeLabel,
    defaultRatingScale,

    // this function will be called whenever the rating scale or type changes
    onChange = () => {},

    defaultRatingTypeLabel,
    NON_NUMBER_RATING_CHAR = "⭐",
    parentClassName = "rating-selector",
    typeSwitchClassName = "rating-type-switch",
    scaleSwitchClassName = "rating-scale-switch",
    outputElementClassName = "rating-selector-output",
  } = arg;

  const ratingSelector = document.createElement("div");
  ratingSelector.setAttribute("class", parentClassName);

  // we'll store the ratingType and ratingScale in the dataset of this selector
  // in case you need it.
  ratingSelector.dataset.ratingType = defaultRatingType;
  ratingSelector.dataset.ratingScale = defaultRatingScale;

  ratingSelector.getState = function () {
    return {
      ratingType: ratingSelector.dataset.ratingType,
      ratingScale: ratingSelector.dataset.ratingScale,
    };
  };

  const ratingOutput = document.createElement("div");
  ratingOutput.setAttribute("class", outputElementClassName);

  // this function is needed in the onClick function of switches
  const showResultLocal = () =>
    showResult({
      outputElement: ratingOutput,
      nonNumberValue: NON_NUMBER_RATING_CHAR,
      ratingType: ratingSelector.dataset.ratingType,
      ratingScale: ratingSelector.dataset.ratingScale,
    });

  const ratingScaleSwitch = createSwitch({
    name: "rating-scale",
    onValue: altRatingScale,
    offValue: defaultRatingScale,
    className: scaleSwitchClassName,
    onLabel: `Rating Scale: 1 - ${altRatingScale}`,
    offLabel: `Rating Scale: 1 - ${defaultRatingScale}`,

    onClick: ({ value }) => {
      ratingScale = value;
      ratingSelector.dataset.ratingScale = value;

      showResultLocal();
      onChange(ratingSelector.getState());
    },
  });

  const ratingTypeSwitch = createSwitch({
    name: "rating-type",
    className: typeSwitchClassName,

    onValue: altRatingType,
    offValue: defaultRatingType,

    onLabel: `Rating type: ${altRatingTypeLabel}`,
    offLabel: `Rating type: ${defaultRatingTypeLabel}`,

    onClick: ({ value }) => {
      ratingSelector.dataset.ratingType = value;
      showResultLocal();

      onChange(ratingSelector.getState());
    },
  });

  ratingSelector.appendChild(ratingScaleSwitch);
  ratingSelector.appendChild(ratingTypeSwitch);
  ratingSelector.appendChild(ratingOutput);

  showResultLocal();

  return ratingSelector;
}

/**
 * Creates a __input__ and __label__ element and wraps it with a <div>
 * e.g.,
 * <div>
 *  <label>The Label</label>
 *  <input type="checkbox" ...other attributes... />
 * </div>
 *
 * see the argument destructuring below to understand function API
 * */
function createSwitch(arg = {}) {
  const {
    onLabel,
    offLabel,

    onValue,
    offValue,

    id = "",
    name = "",
    className = "",

    onClick = () => {},
  } = arg;

  const switchName = name;
  const switchAttributes = {
    id,
    name: switchName,
    class: className,
    type: "checkbox",
  };

  const toggleSwitch = document.createElement("input");

  for (const [name, value] of Object.entries(switchAttributes))
    toggleSwitch.setAttribute(name, value);

  const switchLabel = document.createElement("label");
  switchLabel.setAttribute("for", switchName);
  switchLabel.innerText = offLabel;

  // click event handling
  toggleSwitch.addEventListener("click", () => {
    switchLabel.innerText = toggleSwitch.checked ? onLabel : offLabel;

    onClick({
      id,
      name: switchName,
      active: toggleSwitch.checked,
      value: toggleSwitch.checked ? onValue : offValue,
    });
  });

  const switchWrapper = document.createElement("div");
  switchWrapper.appendChild(toggleSwitch);
  switchWrapper.appendChild(switchLabel);

  return switchWrapper;
}


// see the argument destructuring below to understand function API
function showResult(arg = {}) {
  const { outputElement, ratingScale, ratingType, nonNumberValue } = arg;

  while (outputElement.childNodes.length > ratingScale)
    outputElement.removeChild(outputElement.childNodes[0]);
  while (outputElement.childNodes.length < ratingScale)
    outputElement.appendChild(document.createElement("span"));

  outputElement.childNodes.forEach((child, index) => {
    child.innerText = ratingType === "number" ? index + 1 : nonNumberValue;
  });
}
```

```css
.rating-selector-output > span {
  width: 2ch;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
<p id="state">State...</p>
<hr>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

This version uses a `<form>` and renders multiple questions.

**Details are commented in example**

```js
// Reference <form>
const form = document.forms.interface;

/**
 * @desc Renders the HTML of each question up to the given number
 * @param {number} items - Number of questions to render
 */
function addQuestions(items) {
  const qar = form.qar;
  for (let i = 0; i < items; i++) {
    let q = `
    <li class='item${i + 1}'>
      <input id='que${i + 1}' name='que' class='que' type='text' placeholder='Enter question'> 
      <label style='display: inline-block'>Modify 
        <input name='mod' type='radio' value='${i + 1}'>
      </label>
      <fieldset id='row${i + 1}' name='row' class='row'>
        <a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a>
        <a class='extra hide'></a><a class='extra hide'></a>
        <a class='extra hide'></a><a class='extra hide'></a>
        <a class='extra hide'></a>
      </fieldset>
    </li>`;
    qar.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', q);
    const item = document.querySelector(`.item${i + 1}`);
    [...item.querySelectorAll('a')].forEach((a, idx) => {
      a.textContent = idx + 1;
    });
  }
  form.elements.mod[0].checked = true;
}

addQuestions(3);

// Bind change event to <form>
form.onchange = modify;

// This modifies the question that has the checked mod radio button
function modify(e) {
  // Reference the checkbox the user clicked
  const clk = e.target;
  // Reference all form controls
  const fc = this.elements;
  // Get the value of the mod radio button group
  const mod = fc.mod.value;
  // Reference <input> and <fieldset>
  const que = document.getElementById('que' + mod);
  const row = document.getElementById('row' + mod);
  // If the user clicked the required checkbox...
  if (clk.id === 'req') {
    //...toggle the required attribute to the selected <input>
    que.toggleAttribute('required');
  }
  // If the user clicked the 10 checkbox...
  if (clk.id === 'qty') {
    // ...toggle the selected row 5 a.extra .hide and .show classes 
    row.querySelectorAll('.extra').forEach(ex => {
      ex.classList.toggle('hide');
      ex.classList.toggle('show');
    });
  }
  // If the user clicked the stars checkbox...
  if (clk.id === 'str') {
    // ...toggle the .stars class of row
    row.classList.toggle('stars');
  }
  // Reset the checkboxes immediately
  Array.from(fc.panel.elements).forEach(chx => chx.checked = false);
}
```

```css
input {
  font: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
}

#panel,
label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: max-content;
  padding: 5px;
}

#qar {
  list-style-type: decimal;
  border: 0;
}

.que {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  border: 0;
}

.row.stars a {
  color: transparent;
}

.row.stars a::before {
  content: '⭐';
  color: black;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

[required] {
  outline: red 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<form id='interface'>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Q &amp; A/Rating</legend>
    <fieldset id='panel'>
      <label>Required <input id='req' type='checkbox'></label>
      <label>10 <input id='qty' type='checkbox'></label>
      <label>Stars <input id='str' type='checkbox'></label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id='qar'>

    </fieldset>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```